# Designing an experiment with linear regression analysis: more categories or more observations per category?

Tags: least-squares, linear-model, experiment-design, linear, r-squared

During the design of my experiments I encountered the following question: When doing a linear fit (least squares), does it make more sense to have more categories or more observations per category. In other words: what will give the highest confidence of the fit? The image below illustrates my options (not actual data).

[image: more x-values or more observations per x-value]

**Background:**

During the experiment I will be doing a [Fitt's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts%27s_law) experiment. Here I will ask users to move their mouse cursor from a specific position to a target. This target has a specific size (W) and is positioned a certain distance (D) from the starting position.

[image: Fitt's law experiment from wikipedia]

Fitt's law states that the difficulty of this task (Index of Difficulty (ID)) can be captured in the following formula:

$\mathrm{ID}=\log _{2}\left(\frac{2 D}{W}\right)$

The average time it takes to move to the target (movement time(MT)) can be captured by a linear relationship:

$\mathrm{MT}=a+b \cdot \mathrm{ID}$

**Design of the experiment**

During the experiment with a participant I have a finite amount of time and a can choose to do a small amount of ID's with a lot of repetitions per ID *ór* a lot of different ID's with less repetitions per ID. Let's say that the total number of trials per participant is fixed, what would be my best option?
Does this change the R^2 values? And what will give the highest confidence of the fit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a lot of work you could develop a Bayesian adaptive scheme that allows you to dynamically select test points for each subject based on previous responses.  Short of that, the experimental design (DOE) literature extensively covers your question.  The short answer is that if you are very sure about linearity, you can assign half the values at the lowest point and half at the highest, to get a minimum variance slope estimator.  To hedge your linearity bet you can put a few observations in the middle.  In DOE there are formal design optimality criteria you can use to select the test points.

Comment: You could search here for *D-optimal*, for example https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140526/when-would-you-use-an-i-optimal-design-over-a-d-optimal-design  and there is also Bayesian optimality criteria, for example at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/459023/biased-estimator-obtained-by-optimal-experiment-design

Comment: @Frank, thank you for your answer. At first, this strategy of performing all repetitions at the highest and lowest point seemed intuitive to me as well. However, I was thinking about it as following: By doing the experiment you randomly take values from a standard deviation that follows the linear fit, these becoming your datapoints. By thinking about this way it would not matter if you select all observations at different x-values, because it would correspond to the same error to the fit, right? Or am I overlooking something here?

Comment: Frank, can you suggest a reference for the Bayesian adaptive scheme you speak of?

Comment: I don't know of a central reference.   You might search for Bayesian Design of Experiments and also Bayesian Adaptive Trials.

Comment: @Tammo the variance of a slope estimate is inversely proportional to the variance of the x-points.